# as3- Preloader loads at 98%

Tags: actionscript-3

I need my preloader to load before everything else, so a percentage onscreen as dynamic text called "loader_txt" can indicate the loading of my game. I read some other posts about shells and classes, but I have no idea what they talk about. I'm still a beginner at this.
Any idea how to make this simple?

```
stop();



this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loading);

function loading(e:Event):void {

    var total:Number = this.stage.loaderInfo.bytesTotal;
    var loaded:Number = this.stage.loaderInfo.bytesLoaded;


    loader_txt.text = Math.floor((loaded/total)*100)+ "%";

    if (total == loaded) {
    play();
        this.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loading);

    }
    }
```

Comment: If you mean that the preloader doesn't appear until 98%, it's because you're exporting your assets in frame 1 meaning they're actually loading before the preloader is ready to display.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably using adobe flash professional, therefore just set the assets' "Export in frame 1" property to false in the library. I'd also recommend to set the class exporting to the second frame:
(File->ActionScript Settings...->Export classes in frame [   2   ])

Also, you aren't waiting any user interaction after loading, so when it hits 100%, the program immediately "plays".